# How to rebuild method to a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

how can I rebuild my method:

```
public class PDFCheck {
        public static void testAllFontsAreEmbedded(PDFDocument pdf) throws PDFDocumentException {

                for (PDFFont font : pdf.listFonts()) {

                    if (!font.isEmbedded()) {
                        errorMessageBuffer.append("font not embedded: " + font.getName() + "\n");
                        fontError = "font error";
                    }
               }
```

into a Thread like that here:?

```
public class Task1 implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                       ................
                       ................
                       ................
                       ................
           }
    }
}
```

In main I will do like this:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Task1());
t1.start();
t1.interrupt();
```

I want to do that because I've developed a pdf check tool and a stop button should stop the "font chek" (see above code snippet) when a pdf is too large and takes too long to be checked.

I tried this to build a constructor, but the constructor shows a lot of error messages:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

    public static  void testAllFontsAreEmbedded(PDFDocument pdf) throws PDFDocumentException {

        for (PDFFont font : pdf.listFonts()) {

            if (!font.isEmbedded()) {
                fontError = "font error" + " | ";
            } else {
                fontError = "";
            }
        }
            System.out.println("läuft");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I integrate finally a Thread in this method. The Proble now is that the method just choose all the time the first pdf file of the path...Is my **while** statement at a wrong position?

```
new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    String directory;
                    directory = "C:\\Users\\Tommy\\Desktop\\pdf";
                    File inputFiles = new File(directory);
                    CopyOfSettingsGui.this.running = true;
                    for (File file : inputFiles.listFiles()) {
                        if (file.isFile()) {

                            if (file.getName().endsWith((".pdf"))) {
                        while (CopyOfSettingsGui.this.running) {

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(100);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            System.out.print(file.getName() + "\n");

                        }
                        return;
                    }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.start();
```

Comment: What is the problem? Passing the pdf to the thread or the errormessage to the user ?

Comment: passing the pdf through the thread...see my update

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting an answer with an error message :). Your program crashes inside your pcpdfsupport.dll. I assume, that you don't control the failed jni call by yourself so the error is probably inside the PDFTool or in your usage of it. First, debug your program step by step, to identify the line in which the error occurs and check with the documentation if you are doing something wrong. Check also the forums for info about that error with that tool.

Comment: thank you @Joachim for the hints ;). I'll try my best.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the pdf as described in the answer of Conffusion, but if you want to use `interrupt()` you have to make your thread 'interuptable' This method don't stops the thread unless your thread is invoking methods that throw 'Interrupted Exception' or checks the 'interrupted flag'. So you have to invoke ´Thread.interrupted()´ in every iteration.

```
public void run() {
    for (PDFFont font : pdf.listFonts()) {
       if (Thread.interrupted()){
           return;
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can set a member variable to stop the thread:

```
class PDFCheckThread extends Thread {

    private boolean stop;

    public PDFCheckThread(PDFDocument pdf) {
        this.pdf = pdf;
    }

    public void setStopFlag() {
        stop = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (PDFFont font : pdf.listFonts()) {
            if(stop) {
                return;
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: #
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fef4be8790, pid=10420, tid=8284
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [pcpdfsupport.dll+0x8790]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the PDF to the Task1 constructor and store it in a local variable (within Task1. From within the run() method you can access the PDF document:

```
public class Task1 implements Runnable {
    private PDFDocument pdf;
    public Task1 (PDFDocument pdf) {
        this.pdf=pdf;
    }
    public void run() {
        for (PDFFont font : pdf.listFonts()) {
            if (!font.isEmbedded()) {
                fontError = "font error" + " | ";
            } else {
                fontError = "";
            }
        }
            System.out.println("läuft");
        }
    }
}
```

To launch the thread:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Task1(myPDFInstance));
t1.start();
t1.interrupt();
```

Comment: when I try this my program crashes immediately :S